Parsing Alert Logs to Logic Apps
I have an Azure Monitor setup with an alert that uses Kusto to query details about Conditional Access policy sign-in data. When a user signs in, this alert triggers an action group, which activates a Logic App to send me an email. However, my Kusto query includes information like locations in the search results table, and I want to pass that data to my HTTP request in the Logic App so it can be included in the email. Right now I am using the common schema from Microsoft docs. Need a sense of direction here on how to modify this schema to include the data from my query.
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "schemaId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "data": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "essentials": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "alertId": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "alertRule": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "severity": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "signalType": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "monitorCondition": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "monitoringService": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "alertTargetIDs": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "originAlertId": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "firedDateTime": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "resolvedDateTime": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "description": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "essentialsVersion": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "alertContextVersion": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "alertContext": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



Can you provide your alert json, so that community can provide the schema

To get the desire Prase Json schema you can use below steps:
Firstly, take the json which you are getting from the alert.

Next Click on Use Sample payload to generate schema.
Then it will show like below:
Here again paste your json and click done, then you will get schema according to your alert json.

